# Missing resource value for @salesforce/Schema/User.Name" Error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to display my name and email registered in salesforce using Lightning Web Component.

I imported User.Name and User.Email but still I am getting error.
Could you tell me why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

> Blockquote
>   [Line: 4, Col: 23] LWC1512: Missing resource value for @salesforce/Schema/User.Name
>   [Line: 5, Col: 23] LWC1512: Missing resource value for @salesforce/Schema/User.EMAIL

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USERID_FIELD from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/Schema/User.Name';
import MAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/Schema/User.Email';

const FIELDS = [
    USERID_FIELD, NAME_FIELD, MAIL_FIELD
];

export default class JsSample extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, {'recordId': USERID_FIELD, fields: FIELDS})
    record;

    getName() {
        return getFieldValue(this.record.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }

    getEMail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.record.data, MAIL_FIELD);
    }

    @track inputText = '';

    handleChange(event){
        this.inputText = event.target.value;
    }

    /**
     * 初期化処理
     */
    connectedCallback(){

    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        UserInfo<br>
        <div class="showProperties">
            Name：{name}<br>
            Mail：{eMail}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="おまけ">
        <label for="wireText">Input Text</label><input type="text" id="wireText" onchange={handleChange}/>
        <lightning-formatted-text value={inputText}></lightning-formatted-text>
    </div>
</template>
```

update:
I cannot show my name using this code...

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import MAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.EMail';

const FIELDS = "[NAME_FIELD, MAIL_FIELD]";

export default class JsSample extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    userId = Id;
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$userId', fields: FIELDS})
    user;
    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.user.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }
    get eMail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.user.data, MAIL_FIELD);
    }

    // @track inputText = '';

    // handleChange(event){
    //     this.inputText = event.target.value;
    // }

    // /**
    //  * init
    //  */
    // connectedCallback(){

    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire adaptors use lowercase camel case names, for instance `salesforce` and `schema` (apart from SObject and field names). Your references to the schema objects have incorrect case with the word `Schema`. They should be:

```js
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import MAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
```

I made that correction and then pushed to my scratch org and it compiled and saved correctly.

Comment: But still I cannot display my Name using this code... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: TBH, I never went past resolving the deploy error. I'll take a look as soon as I can to see if I can see why and amend my answer.